# Why is $PSL(2,F)$ such an important group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, simple-groups, unimodular-matrices

I am currently writing a final project on simple groups and my professor said I should focus on "the most important simple group", $PSL(2,F)$. I have also read in Aluffi's algebra book that $PSL(2,F)$ is a "candidate for the most important group in mathematics". I picked up Rotman's 'An Introduction to the Theory of Groups', which has some nice results on $PSL(2,F)$. What I am failing to see is what makes this group so important and what influence it has on the whole of group theory/algebra. I certainly understand why *simple groups* are important, but I fail to see why *this particular simple group* is so important.

Does anyone have any references where I can read more about what specifically makes this group so darn important, or have any specifics on the importance of it? Thanks!

Comment: Check Modular forms.

Comment: This is not really an answer, but $SL(2)$ is immensely important due to its role in representation theory and modular forms. I know very little on these topics, but this is surely related.

Comment: Amongst the finite simple groups they are by far the most ubiquitous. Among the nonabelian simple groups of order up to some number $n$, the proportion that are isomorphic to ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$ for some $q$  (or even for some prime $q$) tends to $1$ as $n \to \infty$. But perhaps that makes them boring rather than important?

Comment: You are taking this sentence too seriously. Instead of worrying about the importance of $PSL(2,F)$, you should gather more facts about it yourself, for the final project (it should be *your* final project) . In the end you can judge yourself.

Comment: A good part of the ubiquity is what we could call "the strong law of small objects", in analogy with "the strong law of small numbers", which is a take-off on "the strong law of _large_ numbers"... :)